# How use recursive type T=mutable.Map[Char,T] in Scala

Tags: scala

I use recursive map as

```
val collect=mutable.Map[Char,Any]()
def next(pos: Int,map: mutable.Map[Char,Any]): Unit = {
                val ch=a(pos)
                val d=map.getOrElseUpdate(ch,mutable.Map[Char,Any]()).asInstanceOf[mutable.Map[Char,Any]]
                for (k <- perehods(pos)) {
                    next(k,d)
                }

            }
next(0,collect)
```

How can I use a cast removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have recursive type aliases, it has to be an actual type:

```
case class RecMap[A](map: mutable.Map[A, RecMap[A]]) {
  def apply(x: A) =
    map.getOrElseUpdate(x, RecMap(mutable.Map.empty))
}

def next(pos: Int, rec: RecMap[Char]) = {
  val ch=a(pos)
  val d=rec(ch)
  for (k <- perehods(pos)) {
    next(k,d)
  }
}
```